# ArrayList + Instance (POO)

Tags: java

Estoy empezando a aprender ArrayList, así que me he propuesto a implementarlo en mis antiguos códigos. os enseño primero el código que tengo con array normal, y como intento implementarlo.

```
//Creo el array de tipo coche que es mi clase
Coche coches [] = new Coche [tamaño];

//este for servirá para añadir datos a las diferentes variables de mi clase

       for (int i = 0; i < coches.length;i++){
           System.out.println("Instancia de coche nº "+(i+1));

           sc.nextLine();

//añado las variables
           System.out.print("Matricula :");
           coches[i].matricula = sc.nextLine();
           System.out.print("Marca : ");
           coches[i].marca = sc.nextLine();
       }
```

**Cuando intento implementar el arrayList en este código me da error,lo hago tal que así.**

```
//creo el array de tipo coche que es mi clase.
ArrayList<Coche> coches = new ArrayList();


for(int i = 0; i < coches.size();i++){

         System.out.println("Instancia de coche nº "+(i+1));
         sc.nextLine();
//añado las variables

coches.add(i,matricula=sc.nextLine());
```

¿Obviamente este ultimo, me da error, como podría añadir en arrayList como añado en array normal?

Comment: ```coches.add(Coche)```, donde Coche es el objeto ya inicial izado

Comment: El primero lleva un tamaño, por eso entra al for. El segundo va vació entonces no hará el for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola @TekeCode pues mira lo que veo en tu código es que solo estás usando el arrayList con el objeto coche, más sin embargo no estas agregando el objeto Coche por iteración.

```
//creo el array de tipo coche que es mi clase.
   List<Coche> coches = new ArrayList<Coche>(); //Esta Lista no contiene no contiene nada, asi que en el for deberás establecer un tamaño.

//Este for es e clásico
for(int i = 0; i < 10 ;i++){
         Coche coche = new Coche();
         System.out.println("Instancia de coche nº "+(i+1));
         sc.nextLine();
   //añado las variables
   coche.setMatricula(sc.nextLine());
   coches.add(coche);
}

//El siguiente código se ejecuta con java 8 o superior, y es para ordenar la lista de coches por matricula, adicional por si llegarás a utilizar.
    Collections.sort(coches, new Comparator<Coche>() {
    public int compare(Coche c1, Coche s2) {
        return c1.getMatricula().compareTo(c2.getMatricula());
    }
}); 

//esto es un foreach
int contador=1;
for(Coche cocheV: coches ){
      System.out.println("Coche número: "+ contador +" con Matricula: " + cocheV.getMatricula());
      contador++;
}
```

Saludos.